# Why does the sound stop working sometimes when watching youtube videos?

Tags: firefox, youtube

Here is the situation:

While watching a youtube video, sometimes, the sound will stop working (even the beggining of the video, which I saw WITH sound, no longer plays the sound) but the image still works 
(video keeps playing) Simply restarting firefox solves the issue..

update:
same problem occurs in epiphany (another web browser available for ubuntu) Restarting epiphany also solves the problem..

fyi: I use Firefox 3.5 on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic koala

If there is anything more you need to help me out, I'll edit it in this post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same thing happens to me - be nice to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one, but the problem seems to have stopped as I solved a wireless connection issue (see this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/82461/why-do-i-regularily-lose-my-wireless-connection). The solution was to install wicd as a replacement for NetworkManager... Maybe this will work for you as well?

Comment: New feature in 2020: The last 6 months of Firefox versions now do this frequently. Seems the Mozilla team has been deleting a lot of old code that Just Worked to make development easier going forwards (seen a few features removed, and that reasoning given), so I suspect this sound issue is another one of the It Works pieces of code they decided to remove, resurrecting a 10-year old bug :(

Comment: @Adam are you saying that our answer here of upgrading to Firefox 4.0.1 no longer works? I will accept a better answer if one comes up!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you upgrade to [Firefox 4.0.1](http://getfirefox.com).
also, use the [SmartVideo Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smartvideo-for-youtube-mytube/). It'll help.
You may also try the [Youtube HTML5 mode](http://youtube.com/html5).